# How to start programming on Audio/Video stream with c++?

Tags: c++, image, audio, video

i know c++ programming language very well. i would like to start programming on Audio/Video/image  processing. i am newbie for these streams.
Please help me out on how should I start or which one should i pick up first? 
What would be the learning curve for beginner like me to catch the concept properly.?

Also , please mention good books or reference for beginner?

Why i am asking this question is i want to do programming for Audio/Video/image processing as professional as hoping that this would add valuable skill in my resume for future growth.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

About image processing:

Book: Digital Image Processing - R. Gonzalez, R. Woods

C++ Library: OpenCV

Comment: Been working with OpenCV's multimedia functionality for a long time, and I tell you it's the worst library for video/audio processing. It's for image processing above anything else, and audio/video APIs of OpenCV are dreadful, buggy, and inefficient.